# Add information message when reading email

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I would like to display an information message for the user when he read a specific email (i.e the email is tagged as external). The message should be displayed in the same way as outlook categories.
I know that I can use Exchange transport rule to achieve that but my client don't want to modify the message itself. He prefers displaying a message in the UI without changing the email body. The other option is to use the Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages interface but as I told, I don't want to modify the email item if possible.

Do you think it is doable with outlook JS addins ?
My need is similar to this one for VSTO addin: [How can my Outlook VSTO Add-in modify the read email form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814150/how-can-my-outlook-vsto-add-in-modify-the-read-email-form)

Comment: You can add non-persistent information information using Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages API [example] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview#addAsync_key__JSONmessage__options__callback_). "InformationMessage" [type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.itemnotificationmessagetype?view=outlook-js-preview) and 'persistent' [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessagedetails?view=outlook-js-preview#persistent).

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if it's possible to execute the fonction as soon as the read form is opened without having to click on an action button ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview) interface provides the  [addAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview#addAsync_key__JSONmessage__options__callback_) method which accepts the `JSONMessage` parameter which represents a JSON object that contains the notification message to be added to the item. It contains a `NotificationMessageDetails` object. Among properties you can find the [persistent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessagedetails?view=outlook-js-preview#persistent) property which specifies if the message should be persistent. Only applicable when type is `InformationalMessage`. If `true`, the message remains until removed by this add-in or dismissed by the user. If false, it is removed when the user navigates to a different item. For error notifications, the message persists until the user sees it once. Specifying this parameter for an unsupported type throws an exception.

In case of categories, the message will be modified.

> Do you know if it's possible to execute the function as soon as the read form is opened without having to click on an action button ?

Web add-ins are run under the context of currently selected item only. You can pin a task pane, then you'll be able to register an event handler to get notified of the change. The event handler should accept a single parameter, which is an object literal. The type property of this object will be set to `Office.EventType.ItemChanged`. When the event is called, the `Office.context.mailbox.item` object is already updated to reflect the currently selected item.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  $(document).ready(function () {

    // Set up ItemChanged event
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.ItemChanged, itemChanged);
    });
};

function itemChanged(eventArgs) {
  // Update on the new current item
}
```

Comment: what about using a contextual addin that will be triggered with ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch ? I was thinking of using a regex that will be always matched in order to run Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages function on each selected item ?

Comment: You may try, I have never tried using universal regex patterns.

Comment: it works when I use the ".*" pattern, but it highlight all strings in the body, that's logic...

Comment: Well, if you are happy with highlighting all strings...

Comment: Not really, but that's how contextual addin work. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Currently the event-based activation of add-in in Read mode is not supported. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.

Currently, Event-based of activation of add-ins is only supported for Compose mode. You can explore more here- [Configure your Outlook add-in for event-based activation - Office Add-ins | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch)